# Listagg distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, listagg, oracle18c

hello I need to select a listagg column that only contains distinct values. Unfortunately I am using oracle 18.c and it doesnt support straight distinct option so I probably have to make it with a nested select (not sure?) I have the following SQL query, I need to listagg the "adrml.email" column with distinct values.

```
select distinct
c.trader_transact
, t.trader_descr
, d.third
, d.f_name
, d.def_phone
, d.def_mail
, d.f_city
, d.country_descr
, d.f_street
, con.first_name
, con.last_name
, adrph.formated_phone_nr
, link.adr
, link.contact
,adrdet.dt
,adrdet.street Contact_Street
,adrdet.post_code
,adrdet.city
,adrdet.country
,adrml.email
 ,LISTAGG(
        adrml.email,
        ' / '
    ) WITHIN GROUP(

    ORDER BY
        d.third
    )

from thr_v_third d
join tra_contract c on d.third = c.customer or d.third = c.supplier
join tra_trader t on t.trader = c.trader_transact
join thr_v_adr_lnk_contact link on link.third = d.third --and link.type = 1 and link.default_contact = 1
join adr_contact con on con.adr = link.adr and con.contact = link.contact
join adr_address_det adrdet on adrdet.adr = link.adr and adrdet.last = 1
left join adr_mail adrml on link.adr = adrml.adr and con.contact = adrml.contact and adrml.deflt = 1
left join adr_v_phones adrph on adrph.adr = link.adr and adrph.contact = link.contact and adrph.deflt = 1 and adrph.type = 1
where t.trader = 32
group by
c.trader_transact
, t.trader_descr 
 ,d.third
, d.f_name
, d.def_phone
, d.def_mail
, d.f_city
, d.country_descr
, d.f_street
, link.adr
, link.contact
, con.first_name
, con.last_name
,adrdet.dt
,adrdet.street
,adrdet.post_code
,adrdet.city
,adrdet.country
,adrml.email
, adrph.formated_phone_nr 
order by d.third
```

so far I am getting duplicate emails in the listagg column. How can I clear this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have:

```
SQL> select d.dname,
  2         listagg(e.job, ', ') within group (order by e.job) jobs
  3  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4  group by d.dname;

DNAME          JOBS
-------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING     CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT
RESEARCH       ANALYST, ANALYST, CLERK, CLERK, MANAGER
SALES          CLERK, MANAGER, SALESMAN, SALESMAN, SALESMAN, SALESMAN
```

This is what you want:

```
SQL> select x.dname,
  2         listagg(x.job, ', ') within group (order by x.job) jobs
  3  from (select distinct d.dname,
  4                        e.job
  5        from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  6       ) x
  7  group by x.dname;

DNAME          JOBS
-------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING     CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT
RESEARCH       ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER
SALES          CLERK, MANAGER, SALESMAN

SQL>
```

So, yes - first find distinct values, then `listagg` them.

Comment: That worked! I also want to include a 2nd listagg function that concats 2 columns into one. Like create a "full name" column that concats "con.first_name" , "con.last_name" into one. How can I combine 2 listagg selects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `XMLAGG` as following to remove the duplicates:

> ```
> SQL> with table1(req) as
>   2  (SELECT 'TEJASH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 'RIDDHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   4  SELECT 'TEJASH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5  SELECT 'REKHA' FROM DUAL)
>   6  SELECT
>   7      REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, REQ, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
>   8          ORDER BY
>   9              REQ
>  10      ).GETCLOBVAL(), ','), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS LIST
>  11  FROM
>  12      TABLE1;
>
> LIST
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> REKHA,RIDDHI,TEJASH
>
> SQL>
> ```

The reason for using `XMLAGG` instead of the `LISTAGG` is to avoid any 4000 characters limit issue.

Using `LISTAGG` also you can achieve it with the use of `REGEXP_REPLACE` as following:

> ```
> SQL> with table1(req) as
>   2  (SELECT 'TEJASH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 'RIDDHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   4  SELECT 'TEJASH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5  SELECT 'REKHA' FROM DUAL)
>   6  SELECT
>   7      REGEXP_REPLACE(
>   8          LISTAGG(REQ, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
>   9              ORDER BY
>  10                  REQ
>  11          ), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS LIST
>  12  FROM
>  13      TABLE1;
>
> LIST
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> REKHA,RIDDHI,TEJASH
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!